# significance of spring classes

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Can some one help me the real significance of 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean` and also `org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter`.

In the second case why can't inject the manager classes needed by using setter methods. Why you have to use the round about way. I'm unable to grasp the real intent of both the classes.

Please someone help me with real time usage examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Doc is your friend:

- MethodInvokingFactoryBean:

  > FactoryBean which returns a value which is the result of a static or instance method invocation.

You can use this MethodInvokingFactoryBean if you have some old legacy code factory. And you want to to have a object created by that Factory as a spring bean.

- ServletContextAttributeExporter

  > Exporter that takes Spring-defined objects and exposes them as ServletContext attributes...
  >   **Useful to make Spring-defined beans available to code that is not aware of Spring at all, but rather just of the Servlet API**

You asked "In the second case why can't inject the manager classes needed by using setter methods." I do not undertand the question, but from what the `ServletContextAttributeExporter` is for, may the answer is: you can not Inject a bean in a class that is not a spring bean too.